# @end missing in implementation context

Tags: objective-c

I do not have enough reputation to post an image.. so hopefully you will be able to help me through this. on the third line where is says "@implementation viewcontroller" my xcode is telling me this "@end is missing in implementation context"
thanks in advance!

```
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    mainInt = 0;
    randomMain = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/1.0) target:self selector:@selector(randomMainvoid) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


- (void)randomMainvoid {
    mainInt +=1;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", mainInt];       
}    


- (IBAction)Start {
    [startButton setHidden:YES];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.0088) target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    pos = CGPointMake(5.0, 6.0);
}
```

Comment: Please. ***Please.*** Grab a basic-level book on Objective-C, this is so fundamental that there's no excuse for asking this. (Also, a bit of common sense: if you are not telling the compiler that this is the end of the class, then how it is supposed to infer that?)

Comment: this is your second question which is going to close. And be sure your  3rd question is good enough, otherwise your account will be of **NO-Use**.

Comment: One great way to solve errors in syntax is to find code that works, and compare yours to it. If you're using Xcode, there are so many sample projects that are easy to download and double check your code against, if you don't do so you're really missing out. Also, read the compiler errors and crash reports - really try to understand them, they're not gibberish they actually are trying to communicate something to you!

Comment: @AnoopVaidya [He didn't.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15757056/missing-context-for-method-declaration)

Comment: @H2CO3: I again answerd there, and I hope will get hard earned +1 ;)

Answer (score 2):

At the end of `@implementation ViewController` you need `@end`

Your .m should look like this:

```
@interface ViewController ()
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    mainInt = 0;
    randomMain = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(1.0/1.0) target:self selector:@selector(randomMainvoid) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}


- (void)randomMainvoid {
    mainInt +=1;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", mainInt];       
}    


- (IBAction)Start {
    [startButton setHidden:YES];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.0088) target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    pos = CGPointMake(5.0, 6.0);
}

@end
```

Comment: Yap, +1 for full code. Perhaps an Amazon link to a good Objective-C book? :P

Comment: I don't know about the user, which country/language he use. He should also learn basic English, the error is straight forward **"@end is missing in implementation context"**

Comment: thanks for the help! after i did what you said i was given two more errors! they both say "Missing context for method declaration" what should i try now?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya And common sense too - and there's no book for that.

Comment: @user2230366: Show them, we will try to solve all your error :)

Comment: @user2230366 Very good. Now google those error messages and accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

After

```
- (IBAction)Start {
    [startButton setHidden:YES];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(0.0088) target:self selector:@selector(onTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
    pos = CGPointMake(5.0, 6.0);
}
```

add `@end`